# Extracting a digit from a number ranging from 0 to 99999

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working at a programm right now where I need to sort an array of numbers ranging from 0 to 99999. In order to do so, one part of the task is to extract the digits from every number of the array, and that can be accomplished by

```
i = number / digit.
```

For example, for the number 23456, I am supposed to start by extracting the number 2, which can be done by using

```
digit = 10000
```

and calculating

```
i = 23456 / 10000 = 2.
```

A recursive call is then supposed to look at the next digit, so in this case we want to get

```
i = 23456 / digit = 3
```

and so on. I know that there are certain methods for this, but how can this be done with using only primitves? I already tried to play around with modulo and dividing the digit, but it's not giving any desired result.

Comment: are you obliged to use a recursive call?

Comment: Yes, I am obligated to use a recursive call.

Comment: Jerry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: what You have tried so far? @Julian

Comment: I tried to play around with modulo and dividing the digit, but because of the recursive call, I always end up with dividing by 0, which is not allowed of course. So I'm searching for another way.

Comment: Post the code that ends up diving by zero. Show your work!

Answer (score 4):

## Basic Formula

The `n`-th digit of a non-negative, integral, decimal number can be extracted by the following formula:

```
digit = ((num % 10^n) / 10^(n-1))
```

where `%` represents modulo division, `/` represents integer division, and `^` represents exponentiation in this example.  Note that for this formula, the number is indexed LSD->MSD starting from 1 (not 0).

This formula will also work for non-decimal numbers (e.g. base 16) by changing `10` to the desired base.  It will also work for negative numbers provided that absolute value of the final digit is taken.  Finally, it can even function to extract the integer digits (but not fractional digits) of a floating point number simply by truncating and casting the floating-point number to an integral number before passing it to this formula.

---

## Recursive Algorithm

So, to recursively extract all of the digits of a number of a certain length in order MSD->LSD, you can use the following Java method:

```
static public void extractDigits(int num, int length) {
    if (length <= 0) {  // base case
        return;
    }
    else {  // recursive case
        int digit = (num % (int)Math.pow(10,length)) / (int)Math.pow(10,length-1);
        /* do something with digit here */
        extractDigits(num, length-1);  // recurse
    }
}
```

This method will never divide by zero.

*Note:  In order to "do something with digit here," you may need to pass in an additional parameter (e.g. if you want to add the digit to a list).*

### Optimization

Since your goal is to extract *every* digit from a number, rather than only one specific digit (as the basic formula assumes), this algorithm may be optimized to extract digits in order LSD->MSD so as to avoid the need for exponentiation at each step.  *(this approach original given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315208/5029307) by @AdityaK ...please upvote them if you use it)*

```
static public void extractDigits(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {  // base case
        return;
    }
    else {  // recursive case
        int digit = num % 10;
        /* do something with digit here */
        extractDigits(num / 10);  // recurse
    }
}
```

*Note:  Any negative number should be converted to a positive number before passing it to this method.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to recursively extract numbers from an integer. It will be in reverse order.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     static void extractNumbers(int n, List<Integer> l) {
         if(n==0)
         return;
         else {
             l.add(n%10);
             extractNumbers(n/10, l);
         }
     }
     public static void main(String []args){
         List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         extractNumbers(456789,result);
        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:-

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    int num=23456;
    int numSize=5;
    rec(num,numSize);
}

public static void rec(int num, int numSize){
    if(numSize==0)
        return;
    int divideBy=(int)Math.pow(10,(numSize-1));
    int out=(int)(num/divideBy);
    System.out.println(out);
    rec((num-out*divideBy),(numSize-1));
    return;
}
```

See the output from here: http://ideone.com/GR3l5d

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by using the for loop by converting the array elements into string.

```js
var arr = [234, 3456, 1234, 45679, 100];

var compare = function(val1, val2) {
  return val1 - val2;
};
arr.sort(compare); //sort function
var extract = function(value, index) {

  var j = "";

  var element = value + "";

  for (var i in element) {
    var val = element[i];
    console.log(parseInt(val)); // this prints the single digits from each array elements
    j = j + " " + val;
  }
  alert(j);
};
arr.forEach(extract); //extract  function..
```